# Use Array Prototype Functions with non-arrays

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

As we know we can use Array prototype methods with function **arguments** just like below.

```
function abc() {
   // As 'arguments' is a array like object which don't have Array prototype functions.
   Array.prototype.push.call(arguments, 30);
   console.log(arguments);
}
abc(10, 20);   // Output is: [10, 20, 30]
```

So like wise I tried to use push on DOM element **classList** like below which gives me an error "Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter".

```
var bodyClassList = document.body.classList;
Array.prototype.push.call(bodyClassList, 'myClass');
```

**Note:** I have just tried to learn concepts so that's why I used push even it has builtin **add()** method.

So my question is:

On which objects we can use Array.prototype methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason is clear from _which has only a getter_. You can use `classList.add('myClass')`

Comment: Hi @Tushar, I didn't understand that error message. Could you please explain in detail.

Comment: How can we check whether any array like objects support Array prototype functions. I mean, with arguments we can use. But with classList we can not.

Comment: It's actually pretty simple, array-like objects don't support most of the Array API. They are array-like in that they have a length property, are enumerable and are indexable. You should not attempt any other Array operations than these on array-like objects.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski—the error is saying that it can't set the *length* property (because it has no setter), it doesn't indicate whether the collection is read–only or not (and since there are setter methods like *add* and *remove*, it's not really read–only).

Comment: @Sivakumar You'll have to refer to the documentation for the array-like object. For example, the [`classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), which defines its `length` property as read-only. An [Argument object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), however, defines its `length` to be assignable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype` methods are quite generic methods that work on all kinds of objects. They're just getting and setting indexed properties and the `.length` of the object they are called on. (And, with ES6, the `.constructor` property of `Array` instances if they need to create a new instance). You can [check the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push) to see what `push` does exactly.

So basically, to answer your question…

> On which objects we can use Array.prototype methods?

…on all objects. That is, objects that don't throw exceptions when they are being operated on. Notice that `push` itself does not throw the error.

Some examples:

```
var x = {0:0, length:1};
Array.prototype.push.call(x, 1);
console.log(x); // {0:0, 1:1, length:2}
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(x)); // [0, 1]
```

```
var y = {0:0, get length() { throw new Error("boo!"); }}
Array.prototype.push.call(y, 1); // throws
```

```
var z = {get 0() { throw new Error("boo!"); }, length: 1};
Array.prototype.push.call(z, 1);
console.log(z); // {0:…, 1:1, length:2}
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(z)); // throws
```

The `arguments` object is very much like `x`. The `classList` is very much like `y`.